# Vectorizing index over a list of dataframes R

Tags: r, list, matrix, vectorization

I have a list of over 100 massive matrices in R.

I'll use a small example list object called `list_matrices`

```
list(structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("x", "y"))), structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b"))))
```

Matrix 1 should be object `x` and matrix 2 should be object `a`

I am trying to index each of the matrices in the list such that if the value of column 1 and the value of column 2 in a row matches, the row is indexed out of the matrix which remains stored as it's own matrix inside the `list_matrices` object. Basically I want to something like this

```
mat_tf<- <-mat[(mat[,1]!=mat[,2],]
```

But on every matrix in the list

I'd also like to add onto each matrix object a new name with `_tf` attached to it so that when I call `list_matrices[[1]]` I'll get back a matrix called `x_tf`

Obviously for loops are not a smart idea so I'm trying to look for ways to vectorize the process. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: For the second part of your post, you can name your list elements whatever you want, but when you extract a list element with `list_matrices[[1]]` you're going to get back just a matrix it won't have a name.

Comment: good catch. that's interesting. I notice that now too, but in my real list of matrices I can actually index into them using the name of the individual matrix. Any ideas what's different?

Comment: Nothing is different you can use the names to extract list elements, I was just clarifying that when you extract a list element, whether by using the name or the position, you get just a matrix the name doesn't follow it around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(list_matrices, function(mat) mat[mat[,1] != mat[,2],])
```

You can then name your list with the `names` function however you want.

Comment: Alright so I did seem to get things to happen with this! Can you explain how the `mat` inside (function) works? So if I had a list of dataframes I wanted to do this to would I change anything?

Comment: Also, do you know a quick and easy solution to check which (using the which function I'm guessing)  to see which of the rows in each matrix this applies to as a good check of whether the function worked?

Comment: It would be the same for data frames. `mat` is just an arbitrary name for the function argument you could make it `df` or `x` or whatever you want. You can run an `lapply` with just the condition check to get a list of logicals indicating the rows